# 'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip

(base) F:>pip3 install nltk
'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

what should i do to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you type `F:\> pip` and hit Enter?

Comment: Usage:
  pip <command> [options]

Commands:
  install                     Install packages.
  download                    Download packages.
  uninstall                   Uninstall packages.
  freeze                      Output installed packages in requirements format.
  list                        List installed packages.
  
 IT WORKS WHEN I TYPE "F:/ PIP"

Comment: What happens when you type `F:\> pip install nltk`?

Comment: (base) F:\>pip install nltk
Requirement already satisfied: nltk in f:\python\lib\site-packages (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six in f:\python\lib\site-packages (from nltk) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: singledispatch in f:\python\lib\site-packages (from nltk) (3.4.0.3)

Comment: i think it works now. thanks I am new to pythton.

Comment: i think it works now. thanks

Comment: What do you see when you type `F:\> echo %PATH%`? I am just curious.

Comment: (base) F:\> echo %PATH%
F:\Python;F:\Python\Library\mingw-w64\bin;F:\Python\Library\usr\bin;F:\Python\Library\bin; .................. C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;E:\gretl                           Is there any problem

Comment: No problem at all. Path looks just fine.

Comment: (base) F:\>conda install -c anaconda nltk
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: done

Comment: The following packages will be UPDATED:
  conda                      pkgs/main::conda-4.6.11-py37_0 --> anaconda::conda-4.6.14-py37_0
The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  ca-certificates                                 pkgs/main --> anaconda
  certifi                                         pkgs/main --> anaconda
  nltk                                            pkgs/main --> anaconda
  openssl                                         pkgs/main --> anaconda
  qt                                              pkgs/main --> anaconda
Proceed ([y]/n)?  y

Comment: Nothing to worry about. See https://superuser.com/questions/1422008/conda-install-packagename-gives-deprecation-warning.

Comment: ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(568): An error occurred while installing package 'anaconda::qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0'.
OSError(22, 'Invalid argument')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

[Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'F:\\Python\\Library\\resources\\icudtl.dat'

Comment: For this issue, open a new question so that we do not mix Q&A between two different questions. Also, be sure to mark one of the answers as accepted if you feel your original question has been answered.

Comment: what should i do with this error which shows when i type "Y"

Comment: Open a new question on StackOverflow and explain what you are trying to install. Also, is this current question answered satisfactorily for you?

Answer (score 18):

On Windows, it's a good idea to stick to launching `pip` via [the `py.exe` common launcher](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/), so you can provide flags to specify which version of Python to use without needing to deal with a complicated `PATH`.

To use it for Python 3, just replace:

```
pip3 RESTOFCOMMAND
```

with:

```
py -3 -mpip RESTOFCOMMAND
```

It's a little bit longer to type, but it avoids a lot of hassles with `PATH` management, and changing it to run on more and more specific Python versions (when you have multiple versions available) is easy; if you want to be sure Python 3.6 is used even if Python 3.7 is available, you'd just change to:

```
py -3.6 -mpip RESTOFCOMMAND
```

Answer (score 1):

On your computer, it appears that you can install using `pip` instead of `pip3`. So, just use:

```
F:\> pip install whatever
```

You should check your system path by doing this:

```
F:\> echo %PATH%
```

You will get `;` separated paths. Find the path to python installation. Chances are you will see `...\Scripts`. You can go to that directory and confirm that you have pip. If you have pip3 installed elsewhere (you can do file search in Windows), you can add that path to your PATH variable.

https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/using-pip-on-windows/5 can help you.